# Displaying table content uniformly distributed on html page

Tags: html, jquery, css

JSP Code:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="map" items="${map}">
  <!--no need to have new tr td here that just add extra row to your table-->
    <tr class="header expand">
      <th>${map.key.id}</th>
      <th>${map.key.name}</th>
      <th>${map.key.status}</th>
      <th><span class="sign"></span></th>
    </tr>
   <!--no need to have different table-->
    <tr>
      <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
      <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
      <th>PRICE</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${map.value}">
      <tr>
        <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td>
        <td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td>
        <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
        <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
$('.header').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

CSS:

```
table,tr,td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;}
tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;}
.header .sign:after {
  content: "-";
  display: inline-block;
}
.header.expand .sign:after {
  content: "+";
}
```

I actually have 11 columns to print under table header.For demo purpose I have given only 4 attributes.I want them to obtain just in middle of table header.That is uniform through the page.I want output something like this:

```
                         123 A 1 +
        123 A *** ***  ***  ***  ***  ***  *** *** 1
```

So on clicking + sign all the rows under table header be shown uniformly through the page.What changes in CSS will make this so?I have tried adding up class in tr but no changes take place in styling of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colspan` to span columns.i.e : here you have `11` column under your header so just use `colspan="11"` as you can see in below code snippet as well :

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
  //this(<span>)->find parent(th)->parent(tr)->next tr("header1")
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').parent().parent().nextUntil('tr.header1').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr.header1 {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #ffff99;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  background: #1a1a00;
}

.header.sign:after {
  content: "-";
  display: inline-block;
}

.expand.sign:after {
  content: "+";
}

span {
  padding: 3px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: pink;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="header1">
    <th colspan="11">${map.key.id} ${map.key.name} ${map.key.status}
      <span class="sign header expand"></span></th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td>
    <td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="header1">
    <th colspan="11">${map.key.id} ${map.key.name} ${map.key.status}
      <span class="sign header expand"></span></th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td>
    <td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: There is no change in output by including colspan.

Comment: can you elaborate ? what doesn't work ? you need op same as above which i have provided in answer or something else?

Comment: Ya its working now..But I want few updates like the data under table header need to be shown only when clicked on + sign ..right now it is being shown when it is clicked anywhere on table header.The other change is when we click on table header it changes it default size to magnify it as per data below it..I just want static size table header which doesn't change size when table is collapsed..

Comment: The pointer cursor need to be shown just for + sign.Its showing for entire table header

Comment: you didn't said that before? anyways .. use `cursor: not-allowed;` to disable cursor..updated answer as well.